# React Error when try to use JSON.parse() inside component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react component that recieve props, one of this props is a json with information that i need to use.

When i try to destructure this prop and try to use this prop, react show me an error:

> The above error occurred in the  component:

> at SimpleResponse (http://localhost:3000/main.687285b21fb2187da652.hot-update.js:50:5)
> at div
> at HomeResponse (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:24186:76)
> at Route (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:143063:29)
> at Switch (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:143265:29)
> at LoadRoutes (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:23066:5)
> at LayoutHome (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:22878:5)
> at Route (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:143063:29)
> at RouteWithSubRoutes (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:262:19)
> at Switch (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:143265:29)
> at Router (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:142698:30)
> at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:142319:35)
> at AuthProvider (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:25487:5)
> at App
> at Provider (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:139564:20)

If i print a console.log with the information, the console print it the data.
But i can not use it inside the component.

This is part of the code:

```
    const SimpleResponse = ({ props, token, retId, retError, listResponse }) => {
  console.log(listResponse); // can see this in console
const {
  response_json_new
} = listResponse;
console.log(response_json_new); // can see this in console
  const dispatch = useDispatch();  
  const {
    typeResponse,
    id_intent,
    description = '',
    id = '',
    title_item = '',
    corpusArea = '',    
    corpusNameId = '',
    response_json_edit = null,
    response_json_production = null,
  } = props;

  let estado;
  let labelEstado;
  if (response_json_production !== null && response_json_edit !== null) {
    estado = 'edit';
    labelEstado = 'En Edición';
  } else if (response_json_production !== null) {
    estado = 'production';
    labelEstado = 'En Producción';
  } else {
    estado = 'new';
    labelEstado = 'Nueva';
  }

  const author = useSelector((state) => state.topics.selectTopic.author) !== "" ? useSelector((state) => state.topics.selectTopic.author) :
    JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('topic')).author;

  const responseSelect = useSelector((state) => state.responses.responses);
// line 50
  //line 51
  let response = responseSelect.find(o => o.id === id); //line 52
```

But after this console appear the error.
someone, can help me, please???
thanks

Comment: The error seems to be at line 50 which is a code we don't see, you only showed the *working* part of your code.

Comment: Ups now i posted it. Thanks

Comment: You should read [the rule of hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level). You shouldn't call `useSelector` conditionally.

Comment: @morganney thanks for your comment but this not result my problem. I know that this hook is violation the rule of hooks, and then i will fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that works for me is check if the listResponse is not undefined, and then if not, use it inside other variable all inside the conditional.

That is part of the code

```
let finalResponseList;
  if(listResponse !== undefined) {
    data = listResponse;
    jsonDataList = JSON.parse(data.response_json_new);        
    finalResponseList = {
      list: {
        text_list: jsonDataList.list.text_list,
        title_list: jsonDataList.list.title_list,
        items_list: [],
    },
    lateral: {},
    finalResponses: {}
    }; 
  }
```